# Why does App_GlobalResources compile for x86, even with "Enable 32-bit applications" set to false in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

A web application I am working on had three x86 dependencies:

- Crystal Reports 32-bit Runtime
- An old homegrown data utility library
- An old homegrown logging library

I took the following actions on our staging server and on my local machine:

- Removed 32-bit CR runtime and installed 64-bit
- Decompiled the two homegrown libraries and placed the needed code in the web application (and removed the referenced to the two assemblies)
- Set "Enable 32-bit applications" to false on the application pool in IIS

The web application now has a 64-bit dependency (the Lync UCMA SDK) which has led to the need for removing the 32-bit dependencies. The problem is that now I receive the following message from IIS in the browser, or from the command line if I try to manually use `aspnet_compile`:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\root\6b69372f\fdfe0d46\App_GlobalResources.melxzfvs.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with
>   an incorrect format.

I have tried the following actions in my attempts to resolve it:

- Clearing the ASP.NET temporary files, where that dll exists
- Running `aspnet_regiis -i` (the 64-bit version)
- Setting the project configuration to x64 rather than "Any CPU"

Viewing the App_GlobalResources dll in a tool like Telerik JustDecompile indicates that the dll is compiled for the x86 platform specifically, even though the 64-bit version of `aspnet_compile` is clearly being run. Every other assembly in the bin folder is 'Any CPU'.

What can I do to make it compile for x64?

Edit:
If I remove the App_GlobalResources folder, the ASP.NET compiler continues to complain, except now it's about App_Code.dll. Same problem.

Comment: Possibly try to explicitly uninstall and reinstall the scripts by doing `aspnet_regiis -u` then `aspnet_regiis -i` then `aspnet_regiis -c`. <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.80).aspx> Worth a shot I suppose, also maybe try a fresh app pool.

Comment: Ran the uninstall from both 32 and 64 bit directories, then installed from 64 bit only and restarted IIS; no luck

Comment: I can't reproduce that issue unfortunately. If you're able to on a dev server, maybe remove the ISAPI Filter for 32-bit versions of .NET to see if it can help you triage problem. Might be a bit drastic, but may help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I just checked another web application, and its App_Code and App_Global get compiled to 'Any CPU' while this project's files like that get compiled to 'x86', whether in Visual Studio with precompilation on the publish profile or in IIS after turning precompilation off.

Answer (score 2):

After some tedious side-by-side comparison of .csproj and Web.config files, I determined that the following section within the web.config was culprit:

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" compilerOptions="/unsafe /platform:x86" warningLevel="1">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0" />
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

After removing this section, the App_Code, App_GlobalResources and their kin all compiled for "Any CPU".

Comment: My guess is that this was a remnant of the old web site project. When we converted it to a web application project a year or so ago, we probably copied this bit over from the old config along with everything else.